# In Google sheets use Value from a Cell ( retrieved with =MATCH ) to get Information from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Im new to google sheets and might be doing this all wrong.
Im trying to get information from another sheet by using the value from a cell in my current sheet.

In the current sheet, I have a column of IDs
This is populated by looking at the Data sheet and finding "foo" and returning the row number

```
=MATCH("foo",Data!A:A,0)
```

This will return 2 for example

I would then like to use this number to  reference a cell in data sheet

```
=Data!E2
```

I would thought it can be done with something like this

```
=Data!E=MATCH("foo",Data!A:A,0)
```

Comment: Can you give public access to the sheet shared below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDIRECT("Data!E"&MATCH("foo", Data!A:A, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply this gives an error of
"Error
Unknown range name: 'E'."

I have made a test sheet to help explain
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13oc8ag0ymX7X85JgRlIjKje69ofaKYsNZ7ljsHclpl4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think player0 forgot to add the quotes around Data!E. See if this helps =INDIRECT("Data!E"&MATCH("foo", Data!A:A, 0))

Comment: Thank you ever so much, That has worked. 
You guys are amazing, I have spent hrs looking at this